# Input tag value to change color on hover

Tags: css

I have an input tag nested inside a list tag. Here is the code:

```
<li class="button"><input name="submit_details" type="submit" value="Next" /></li>
```

Now when I use the following style:

```
 .button:hover{color:#ffffff},
```

the text value  "Next" does not change color(to white) when I hover over it.

Any suggestions on how to make that work?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! There is no need to prefix your question titles with "CSS:". That is what tags are for.

Comment: have you tried `.button:hover input{color:#ffffff}`?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, that works. Appreciate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to target the `input` itself as opposed to the `li`:

```
.button input:hover { color:#fff }
```

Or if you want the `input` text color to turn white upon `li` hover:

```
.button:hover input { color:#fff }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following, which works in Firefox:

```
input[type='text']:hover{color:red}
```